# ¿que tengo que cambiar del addtabelmodellistener para que pueda modificar una lista?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, model

```
@Override
public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
    super.addTableModelListener(l);
}
```

tengo un problema tengo que ocupar el addtablemodellistener para hacer un evento y de ahi modificar datos de una fila de una tabla pero no se como hacerlo.

```
public void oyenteCambio(PropertyChangeListener oyente){
   cambio.addPropertyChangeListener(oyente);
}
```

tambien tengo esto en un oyente para que cambie los datos tanto en la tabla (ram) como en un archivo es en java